# conversion of BSON value 'xxx' of type 'bson.symbol' not supported

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am running MongoDB version 3.2.9 and when I run a mongoexport, the export stops at some point because of the error

```
mongoexport --db myapp --collection events --out events.json
```

> Failed: conversion of BSON value 'student' of type 'bson.Symbol' not supported

I believe this is what the MongoDB team mentionned in the JIRA tracker ([ref](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1105)) but I still don't know what I can do to go around it.

Is there a way to ignore errors and eventually export the data with placeholders or convert symbols to strings during the export ?

Answer (score 2):

You can download version 2.6 of the server from the [Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center) (look for the text "Previous Releases") and use mongoexport from that.  The Symbol type will be converted to string, so it's lossy but since Symbol is deprecated, that's probably a good thing anyway.

Comment: Hum the database in question in on a production server on the Amazon cloud... is there something easier than to restore a snapshot on a different machine, and roll back MongoDB version there ?

Comment: I don't mean downgrade the database.  I mean unpack the tarball and take the "mongoexport" binary from the tarball and use it against the 3.2.9 database you want to export from.

Comment: Oh my, sometimes I'm just dense. Thanks !

Comment: Hey, the old mongoexport seems to be incompatible with Database authentication using `--username`, `--password`, and `--authenticationDatabase`... any hint ?

Comment: The database is probably using SCRAM-SHA1 for authentication and the old client doesn't support that.  Your best option is probably to use a recent MongoDB client (that supports both SCRAM-SHA1 and symbol) and write the export to JSON yourself.  FWIW, fixing this is on the horizon for the MongoDB 3.6 release and you can track the status in Jira ticket [TOOLS-1610](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1610).

Comment: Yes I tried to download the most recent version of mongodump yesterday from the latest MongoDB release to do that but it still wasn't working :S

I should be able to use just the mongodump binary with my existing MongoDB 3.2.9 ?

Anyway thanks for the link.